# disable after its execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 events

First:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if (($(this).scrollTop()+h) >= $(".services-procent-ul").offset().top){
        circle();
        $(window).off("scroll");
    }
});
```

Second:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
  $('.nav2').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.nav1').fadeOut('fast');
}else{
  $('.nav2').fadeOut('fast');
  $('.nav1').fadeIn('slow');
}
});
```

The first event I need to disable after its execution. But I need to work a second event.

Answer (score 5):

You can add [event namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) to first event and disable it then  by namespace wherever you want:

```
$(window).on("scroll.once", function() {
    ...
    $(window).off("scroll.once");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "disable" an event after its execution You could use Jquery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

The  .one() method is identical to  .on(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation

```
$(window).one("scroll", function() {
   //doSomething
});
```

If you are looking for a way to disable certain event callback after certain condition and not disable all of them You can add [Event Namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) as  @antyrat answered

Comment: I guess it will stop after scroll start in that case. But OP want's to stop it only once it hits the specific condition

Comment: @antyrat yes, you are right but OP question is not clear about that, he is specifically saying 2 times that the event needs to be disabled after its execution ;).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$.Callbacks("once")` to call `circle` at most once if condition `($(this).scrollTop()+h) >= $(".services-procent-ul").offset().top` returns true

```
    var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once");

    callbacks.add(circle);

    var scroller = function() {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $('.nav2').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.nav1').fadeOut('fast');
          } else {
            $('.nav2').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.nav1').fadeIn('slow');
          }
       }

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if (($(this).scrollTop()+h) >= $(".services-procent-ul").offset().top) {
            callbacks.fire()
        } 
        scroller()

    });
```

Comment: Are you sure it will not stop right after window scroll event starts? For example if `$(this).scrollTop()` will become from 0 to 1 and condition will be not executed everything will get broken

Comment: still wrong behavior, `scroller` will work but `circle()` will not execute.

Comment: @antyrat Added `circle` to `else` statement

Comment: wrong again :) Now `circle()` will be executed every time. OP want's it to be executed only if `($(this).scrollTop()+h) >= $(".services-procent-ul").offset().top` condition will work. And you can't achieve this using `one()`. Because of `scroll` event. It will stop immediately after `scroll` event will be started and  `scrollTop` will not change anymore

Comment: @antyrat See updated post ; substituted `$.Callbacks("once")` for one . `circle` should be called at most one time

Comment: ok, but `circle` now can be executed more than once :) And OP want it to execute only once. Your answer become more complicated than OP question...

Comment: @antyrat _"ok, but circle now can be executed more than once :) "_ No , `circle` should be called at most once using `$.Callbacks("once")`

Comment: Ok, but now you should move `scroller` outside of if condition as it will not work as OP expect